# How to update Session variable synchronously between server side and client side?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, session-variables

I have to populate logs in a html view, and logs are generated in server side. Here's the code I tried,

C# method,

In Global.asax,

```
Session["sessionVariable"] = "test";
```

A method pointed from controller,

```
public void SomeOperation()
    {
      //some operation
      foreach(string obj in MainObject)
      {
         Session["sessionVariable"] = obj;
      }
    }
```

HTML View,

```
<script>

  var showFromCookies = function () {
            var test = '@Session["sessionVariable"]';
            //console.log(test);
        };

<script>
```

Now, 'test' from global file logs to the console. However the foreach loop has no impact, I am not sure if session variable isn't changing or javascript couldn't fetch it ! Please help.

Comment: Why don't you use ASP.NET MVC's ViewBag or TempData?

Comment: Its not a controller, controller is pointing to method from a different class. I don't see any ViewBag or TempData there !

Comment: your Foreach is not 100% Clear You are overwriting the Session over and over again? why would you that ? why not just take the last element of the mainobject?

Comment: I just gave an example there, Indeed I'm overwriting the Session data with 'logs' generated in the code. As those logs are generated only at run time, I don't see any other option to go with.